# Getting error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/certicom/security/cert/internal/x509/Base64

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception, vaadin7, weblogic12c

All of sudden my code started throwing error on with below exception. I tried searching on websites but didnt get much information.
Windows Server 2012 R2 
Weblogic Server 12.1.3.0.0
Vaadin Framework Version 7.1.12

> <25-Sep-2015 12:08:38 o'clock CEST>
>
> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default
>   (self-tuning)'> <> <> <> <1443175718795>  <
>   com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager$RpcInvocationException: Unable to
>   invoke method click in com.vaadin.shared.ui.button.ButtonServerRpc    at
>   com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:170)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:118)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleBurst(ServerRpcHandler.java:207)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:111)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:91)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:37)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1382)
>     at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:238)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
>     at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
>     at com.csa.ui.EncodeFilter.doFilter(EncodeFilter.java:25)   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3436)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
>     at
>   weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
>     at
>   weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
>     at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)  at
>   weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263) Caused By:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor78.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:168)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:118)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleBurst(ServerRpcHandler.java:207)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:111)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:91)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:37)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1382)
>     at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:238)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
>     at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
>     at com.csa.ui.EncodeFilter.doFilter(EncodeFilter.java:25)   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3436)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
>     at
>   weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
>     at
>   weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
>     at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)  at
>   weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263) Caused By:
>   com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod$MethodException: Invocation of method
>   buttonClick in com.csa.ui.componant.NewMailDialogue failed.   at
>   com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:528)
>     at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:198)     at
>   com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:161)  at
>   com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:969)
>     at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:368)  at
>   com.vaadin.ui.Button$1.click(Button.java:57)  at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor78.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:168)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:118)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleBurst(ServerRpcHandler.java:207)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:111)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:91)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:37)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1382)
>     at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:238)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
>     at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
>     at com.csa.ui.EncodeFilter.doFilter(EncodeFilter.java:25)   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3436)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
>     at
>   weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
>     at
>   weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
>     at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)  at
>   weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263) Caused By:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/certicom/security/cert/internal/x509/Base64   at
>   com.csa.ui.componant.NewMailDialogue.buttonClick(NewMailDialogue.java:259)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor79.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:508)
>     at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:198)     at
>   com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:161)  at
>   com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:969)
>     at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:368)  at
>   com.vaadin.ui.Button$1.click(Button.java:57)  at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor78.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:168)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:118)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleBurst(ServerRpcHandler.java:207)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:111)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:91)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:37)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1382)
>     at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:238)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
>     at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
>     at com.csa.ui.EncodeFilter.doFilter(EncodeFilter.java:25)   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3436)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
>     at
>   weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
>     at
>   weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
>     at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)  at
>   weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
>   >

Thanks

Comment: *All of (a) sudden* does not exist. Something changed. What?

Comment: Well nothing is changed on server, but i guess this is the first instance when that class got called.

Answer (score 0):

Well this was a silly error. The war file was built with lower version of java and weblogic runtime hence the class was missing.
I rebuilt the war with newer configuration and everything worked fine.